# A pythonic way how to find if a value is between two values in a list

Tags: list, grid, range, python, snapping

Having a sorted list and some random value, I would like to find in which range the value is.

List goes like this: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
And value is, say 8.

The standard way would be to either go from start until we hit value that is bigger than ours (like in the example below), or to perform [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).

```
grid = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
value = 8
result_index = 0
while result_index < len(grid) and grid[result_index] < value:
    result_index += 1

print result_index
```

I am wondering if there is a more pythonic approach, as this although short, looks bit of an eye sore. 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> grid = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
>>> value = 8
>>> bisect.bisect(grid, value)
2
```

Edit:

[bisect — Array bisection algorithm](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html)

Comment: +1, beat me to it by ten seconds. Would be worth linking to the stdlib docs though.

Comment: i guess i did not find the right terms to search with! Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: O gosh, another WET language! :) funny to see how python (even though to suffering from a rigid type system as Java) nevertheless forces you to write everything twice.

Comment: Adrian, no-one is forcing you to write everything twice. If you intended it to be a joke, I didn't get it; if you meant it, you don't know Python well enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
for min, max in zip(grid, grid[1:]): # [(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15, 20), (20, 25)]
  if max <= value < min: #previously: if value in xrange(min, max):
    return min, max
raise ValueError("value out of range")
```

Comment: What happens if `value=2, grid = [3, 2**30]` ?

Comment: If your grid is `[3, 2**30]` chances are you have worse trouble than this. The real problem of this solution is that it only works for integer values of `value`.

Comment: Point is that generating all the possible values in the range is terribly inefficient compared to `value >= min and value <= max`. Also, what happens if `value=20`?

Comment: `xrange(15, 20)` will yield `15, 16, 17, 18, 19`, so the above should return `20, 25`.

You do raise a point, however. The real corner case is `value = 25` where `None` will be returned.

Comment: Oh, right, 25 is just in badp's example --- I didn't see that. :-)